# Map string to Enum with Null check in C#

Tags: c#

I am calling api that in returning gender to me (male or female) as a string. I need to map this value to the enum gender  that I have, not sure how add Null check. This line is mapping male or female correctly, but when the api returns null for gender it gave error. How I can pass null or have map to unknow?

//This is the line that maps string to enum

```
 insurance.Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), patientById.insurance.subscriber_gender);
```

Gender comes from this class:

```
 public Data.Gender? Gender { get; set; }
 public enum Gender { Female, Male, Unknown }
```

Comment: There is an Enum.TryParse as well...

Comment: a) Look up `FastEnum` b) To do a null check `patientById.insurance.subscriber_gender == null`.

Comment: You probably want to change your `Gender` enum so that `Unknown` is the first value. That makes it the default, and it will be returned by `TryParse` when the string is not valid.

Comment: @JackA. The field is nullable - they will want `null`, not `Unknown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like (assuming that `null` means "hey, I can't parse this"):

```
public void SetGenderFromString(string genderString)
{
    if (Enum.TryParse<Gender>(genderString, out var gender))
    {
        Gender = gender;
    }
    else
    {
        Gender = null;
    }
}
```

It would be different if you want a null or empty string to map to null, and a failed parse to map to unknown.  But, a little `string.IsNullOrEmpty` could fix that quickly.  You could even check for a string like `"null"` (case invariant, perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    [Test]
    public void ParseSomeEnumsOrDefault()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ParseOrDefault<TestEnum>("Male"));
        Console.WriteLine(ParseOrDefault<TestEnum>(null));
        Console.WriteLine(ParseOrDefault<TestEnum>(null, TestEnum.Female));
    }

    public enum TestEnum
    {
        Unknown,
        Male,
        Female
    }

    public static T ParseOrDefault<T>(string input, T @default = default)
    {
        object res;
        if (Enum.TryParse(typeof(T), input, out res))
            return (T)res;
        return @default;
    }
```

Output:

```
Male 
Unknown
Female
```

**PS:**

First element in enum has index 0 so it becomes default. So, try to place "Unknown"/"Empty"/"Undefined" on first place in enum.

Comment: It's much easier to use `Enum.TryParse<Gender>`.  For example: `Enum.TryParse<Gender>(genderString, out var gender)`

Comment: Use if you want. I just love to use Monad approach in developing small generic helper functions. You can also return null if you really want, but Unknown in enum usually means and created to simulate nullables.

Comment: @Flydog57: True. But then it's only usable for the `Gender` enum. I see the benefit of this function as being reusable for any enum.

Comment: OK, then consider `public static T ParseOrDefault<T>(string input, T @default = default) where T: struct, Enum`  and then `Enum.TryParse<T>(input, out var res)`